# jQuery hide and show when the data matches

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a snippet and I am working a jQuery show/hide when the data attr matches.
HTML structure is like below

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item" data-item="1">1
        <div class="inside" data-content="1">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-item="2">2
        <div class="inside" data-content="2">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item" data-item="2">3
            <div class="inside" data-content="3">

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the class `class="item"` will be append (ed) to `outside` div, I'd like to achieve that, 
if content data-num is existing, do not "`append()`", `show()`instead, then the slides can be showed properly. I wanted to learn how to check if `data-num` existing?

so the concept is like that, 
if click on class `item` if `item` 's `data-item`(e.g. `data-item = "2"`) matches `outside` > `content data-num` (e.g `data-num = "2"` ), then `show()` that content class.
Hope I made it clear.  Thanks a lot.

Here is **online sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8VD9R/**

[image]

Comment: You could learn a lot here:
[jQuery_4_U](http://www.jquery4u.com/data-manipulation/jquery-data-html5-custom-data-attributes/)

Let me post a working project. One moment.

Comment: Honestly, I have a working demo, but I'm trying to expand it. Give me till tomorrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over the content class.
I am writing the sample code here ,Please update it accordingly:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
$('.content').hide();
$('.content').each(function(i, obj) {
  if($(this).attr('data-item')==$(obj).attr('data-num'))
  {
    $(obj).show();
    return;
  }
});

});
```